# Fatal error: Call to a member function format () on boolean

Tags: php, wordpress

My booking pluging on wordpress is not working
It say
Fatal error: Call to a member function format () on boolean in ...

and say me to go to this line of archive

```
public static function convert_date_to_mdY( $date_string, $date_format = null ) {
    if ( ! $date_format ) {
        $date_format = AWE_function::get_current_date_format();
    }

    if ( 'm/d/Y' == $date_format ) {
        return $date_string;
    }

    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat( $date_format, $date_string );
    return $d->format( 'm/d/Y' );
}
```

What´s the problem?

Comment: The answer below is correct check the [documentation on DateTime::createFromFormat return value](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-returnvalues)

Answer (score 5):

`DateTime::createFromFormat()` is returning false, indicating that it was unable to create the DateTime from the values provided. The code does not error check the return value.

It should be error checking, but perhaps the parameters, which may be coming from something set in the GUI are incorrect, and correcting them may solve the problem. Check the date format and the supplied $date_string if possible.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that DateTime::createFromFormat() will be unable to create the DateTime if values thrown into it have different Format other than DateTime.

For example, if any TEXT or STRING is thrown into it as its values, then it will produce error.

Date is separated by '.' or by '-' or by '/'.
Time is separated by ':'.

This constitutes basic FORMAT of DateTime.

Use IF condition to check whether NULL Values or TEXT values are given into it which are different from DATETIME FORMAT.

Also, [type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) of variable should be checked. 
Also, it should be checked, if given variable is an [object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php)?
Also, Format should be from following : -

w3schools -> func_date_date_format

With thanks,
Sukumar

Comment: Thx, your answer really helped me :)